# Calculating acreage as a percentage in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, calculate-values

I am struggling to calculate the acreage as a percentage in Calculate Field Management, but I am getting this error message:

> "ValueError: could not convert string to float! BufferAcreage!

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "BuffAcreage", "!shape.area@acres!", "PYTHON", "")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "BuffPct", float("!BufferAcreage!")/float("!Acres_Whole!") * 100, "PYTHON", "")
```

The initial line of code works perfectly, but it is the second line of code when I am calculating the acreage percentage that I run into the error.

It will not calculate the field because for some reason it is telling me that I am treating the values in these attributes as strings and will not convert them to floats.

It must be done with the `arcpy.CalculateField_management()`.  I can not use an alternative python scripting method because the assignment directions stipulated that I must use the Calculate Field tool in my script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from the encapsulation of the arguments passed to [Calculate Field](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000), from the help:

> CalculateField_management (in_table, field, expression,
>   {expression_type}, {code_block})

Your calculation syntax `float("!BufferAcreage!")/float("!Acres_Whole!") * 100` is undecipherable by the python parser to the function, as it's several units separated by a space. Each element passed must be a single unit (long, string, list, tuple etc..) which is why the first statement worked fine but the 2nd had a hiccup.

Amending the calculation syntax to:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "BuffPct", "float(!BufferAcreage!)/float(!Acres_Whole!) * 100", "PYTHON")
```

parses the calc as a single string which the calculator will substitute `!field!` with the field value for each row/feature. Note any `{parameter}` is optional so you don't need `,"")` at the end for the code block so I've removed it.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am still a novice when it comes to Python let alone coding in general, but I hope to continue to learn how to incorporate Python into geoprocessing.